# React Navigation Typescript namespace not found

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

When I'm trying to create any navigator( tab/ stack/ drawer) I get this typescript error: `Cannot find namespace 'Tab'` even when it's defined in the file itself.
What's the problem and what's the solution?
I've used the expo typescript template to begin.

**Code:**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import React from "react";

type bottomTabParams = {};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<bottomTabParams>();

const MyTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MyTabs;
```

**Code with error:**
[image: Problem]

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.2",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "private": true
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @AnhDevit that file is not being imported anywhere yet. The error is only in the file. That's all the code that needs examination.

Comment: I just want to check your code behind the pop up

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried using the .tsx extension instead of .ts ? I had the same issue and this was my problem.

Comment: Which extension would you recommend?

Comment: I mean : your filename ends in .ts and it should probably end with .tsx

Comment: Damn, I should bang my head on the wall. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I also got this error in one of my projects. Must use .tsx like .jsx

Answer (score 0):

Why it can be simple like that?

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```

Comment: It's optional, the problem persists nonetheless. It was added to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: what is your version react-navigation? and Did you install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs?

Comment: If I've imported it I must have installed it right? Or wouldn't that be the error in the first place? Anyways I've updated the question with dependencies.